# How to add two scripts to html: locally and from Internet?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add two scripts in my project:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/assets/noty/jquery.noty.min.js"></script>
```

First script locales in Internet, his added right. However other js-file stores locally (path src/assets/noty)
[Plugging in script from Internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiiWB.png)
[Plugging in locally script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKJtF.png)

But the browser try to plug in my second script from global URL. There is no such file of cause => script wasn't plug in.

May be I specify incorrect path? May be exist key-word, that specifies on locally file

Comment: Perhaps you need `src="/assets/noty/jquery.noty.min.js"` on that second script!

Comment: A better question would probably be... Why are using jQuery 1.9 for anything in 2022?

Answer (score 1):

This address `src/assets/noty/jquery.noty.min.js` will be accessed from the client's computer. You should let this file be available publicly on your server.

Also, you are using a relative path. It means that if I'm at `https://yoursite.com/about/` this address beginning with `src/...` will be appended at the end of the current URL, so this js file should be available at `https://yoursite.com/about/src/assets/noty/jquery.noty.min.js` to avoid this you can use a `/` at the beginning, this slash means the root of your URL, it means that even if you are at `https://yoursite.com/about/` the `/about/` path will be ignored and the js file will be always at `https://yoursite.com/src/assets/noty/jquery.noty.min.js` no matter your current address.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make sure the path you included is correct, in the case of the image you shared, if the `src/` directory is in the `http://localhost:3000/src/` path, you can include your script non-relatively this way:

```js
<script src="/src/assets/noty/jquery.noty.min.js"></script>
```